# Non-scrollable RecyclerView with scrollable parent

Tags: android

I have multiple views in my activity, including 2 vertical (1 row) `RecyclerViews`. I disabled the scrolling on the RecyclerViews with `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` and just want to make the whole activity scrollable.
That doesn't work as expected. Touching views outside of the `RecyclerViews` (my `AppBarLayout`) triggers the scrolling, but as soon as I try to scroll within one of the `RecyclerViews`, its not working anymore. Do I have to pass the touch event to my main view or is there any other solution?

My layout looks like this (stripped):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView>

            <LinearLayout>

                <TextView />

                <TextView />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: Just added a picture. Touching the red part scrolls the whole activity as expected, but touching the blue part doesn't scroll anything.
[image]

Comment: Try my answer. hope this will help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use `NestedScrollView` as a container of your `Button` and `RecyclerView` layouts.
2. Set `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to `NestedScrollView`
3. Use `CoordinatorLayout` as a root layout.

**Try this structure:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <ImageView>
            <LinearLayout>
                <TextView />
                <TextView />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:scrollbars="none" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:scrollbars="none" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 6):

Use RecyclerView inside the  NestedScrollView

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />


  </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Just updated my question with a picture. Is your answer still valid?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly then it should be . Make sure all your component with in the NestedScrollView

Answer (score 0):

Override onInterceptTouchEvent method and return true. This stops children from processing touch events.

```
@Override

public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The recyclerview is first laid out to a fixed height if it is wrapped lets say by a ConstraintLayout. Once that occurs it is going to use its own mechanism to recycle rows as you scroll. If you set it not to scroll, well it will do just that and remain recycling rows, so you might only see a few.

The recyclerview needs to be in a container which gives it room to expand without any constraints. So for instance this solution worked for me having my recyclerview wrapped in a RelativeLayout in the middle of a ConstraintLayout.

p.s. If you just copy a solution without understanding how and why, then you are simply hacking.

```
<ScrollView...>
  <ConstraintLayout...>
   ...
               <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/inventory_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/inventory_title">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
   ...
  </ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```